# Obtener email mediante facebook API Graph

Tags: angularjs, facebook-api

Estoy creando una aplicación con AngularJs y quisiera hacer un login de Fb, estoy usando el API Graph de Facebook y me regresa todos los datos excepto el email.

esta es mi funcion:

```
$scope.me = function() {
  Facebook.api('/me?fields=name,email' , function(response) {
    $scope.user = response;
  });
};
```

Comment: Buenas, realizaste la configuración en facebook en la cual dice que tu aplicación solicitará el mail? Saludos

Comment: ¿que configuración debo realizar en Facebook?
Porque en los elementos aprobados de inicio de sesión por default dice que puedo obtener el email